# How does the figure eight ferris wheel work?

Tags: mechanical-engineering

I saw a [story on CNN today](http://www.cnn.com/2015/11/05/travel/macau-studio-city-wheel/index.html) about a figure-eight ferris wheel being built in Macau.

I'm curious what path the cabins take, and how this occurs. Do they actually follow a figure eight pattern? Do they move from one wheel to the other somehow?

The story has a picture with the caption

> The cabins don't actually cross in the middle. They follow a gourd-shaped track. Each ride takes around 15 minutes.

I don't understand what that means. A "gourd-shaped" track?

Comment: [gourd](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gourd), though you can also visualize a stylized hourglass

Comment: @DCShannon Some gourds (such as [this one](http://blogs.ntm.org/rachel-chapman/files/2012/07/gourd.jpg)) are an excellent description for the shape of the track.  Others (such as [this one](https://images.blogthings.com/thegourdtest/gourd-8.jpg)) not so much.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It looks like the cars don't actually move in a figure eight, though it is designed to look like they do from afar. In the image below you can see that the cars travel around an hourglass-shaped (or gourd-shaped) track which is behind the outer yellow steel structure that looks like a figure eight.

[image]

They describe the track as gourd-shaped because some gourds, such as the one shown below, describe the shape of the track very well even though others do not.

[image]